# Google Maps API shows only a marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I was developing an App that consumes Google Maps API,

Firstly I published my app, and added the SHA1 key generated by google in console to map API.

It worked and maps displayed normally.

I then fixed some bugs, and I create a new release, and it was published properly and worked.

But when I open the activity that shows the maps, they are not shown: only the marker and overlay are displayed.

I rechecked SHA1 in maps API and play console match.

[image]

How to solve that?

Before my app was published I tested it and it worked

[image]

**SOLVED**

Maybe I set the wrong SHA1 Key from google - There is a 2 block certificate (App signing certificate and Upload certificate)
I reset the SHA1 from App signing certificate to maps API.

I am not sure, if I added the wrong SHA1 while signing, maps aren't fully shown, it's showing the marker only.

Comment: Are using google signin app?

Comment: yes it is, I add Application restrictions in maps API, and add SHA1 from google

Comment: after reentry SHA1 signing its works